# How to call RESTful web service automatically

Tags: javascript, java, android, node.js, firebase-realtime-database

How do i call a NodeJS RESTful Web service automatically when a data is stored in Google Realtime Firebase? For example, once i stored user details to firebase my restful webservice should detect the data and perform changes on the data. My code works perfectly fine but my question is how do i make it perform automatically without me running the server remotely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using two ways:

**(1) Traditional approach:**

you can implement polling, basically calling your rest API again & again at a 
   certain interval; get the data & check for change

**(2) Websockets(I like it more)**:

You can also use WebSockets, basically, web sockets can maintain a live two way communication with the server
. Reference on how to use WebSockets can be found here
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use an event listener and depending on the event a specific part of your code will be executed. Check the documentation for what suits you https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data